# Array "mapping"

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array of items, for example:

```
var names = ['Rita', 'Sarah', 'Lisa', 'Joe', 'Ralph', 'Linda', 'Richard', 'Chris'];
```

And I have an array of numbers, for example:

```
var numbers = [2, 3, 5, 7];
```

How would I use these numbers to *act* as order numbers to get specific names?

---

What I mean by that?

Have a function that takes those two arrays and gives me an output:

```
output = ['Lisa', 'Joe', 'Linda', 'Chris'];
```

Does JavaScript have any specific functions for that or would I need to code something myself?

Comment: Note: in JS index starts with `0`. So `2` will point to `Joe` and not `Lisa`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** for that

```js
var names = ['Sarah', 'Lisa', 'Joe', 'Ralph', 'Linda', 'Richard', 'Chris'];
var numbers = [2, 3, 5, 7];

var res = numbers.map(function(v) {
  return names[v - 1]
})

// with ES6 arrow function
// var res = numbers.map(v => names[v - 1]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

---

Or using **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
var names = ['Sarah', 'Lisa', 'Joe', 'Ralph', 'Linda', 'Richard', 'Chris'];
var numbers = [2, 3, 5, 7];

var res = names.filter(function(v, i) {
  return numbers.indexOf(i + 1) > -1;
})

// with ES6 arrow function
// var res = numbers.filter((v, i) => numbers.indexOf(i + 1) > -1);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Could I adapt same technique with (JSON) objects? Just a single object that contains same names.

Comment: Oops, I didn't make myself clear enough.. Something like this `{ 0: 'Sarah', 1:'Lisa' etc }`